# *Edited with jsfiddle* ---- jQuery Isotope - forcing position

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

Is it possible to force opened jQuery Isotope divs to open above all the other ones forcing them down - so even if a box is at the bottom it will jump to the top once clicked on?

At the moment it looks quite random - some jump down a line, some move over to the right, etc. What I am trying to do is once a div is clicked on it jumps up to the top left and takes over the whole line while the other unclicked divs all jump down to the line below.

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link is http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/gPuD9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sorting and [`updateSortData`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#updatesortdata) to move the newly clicked item to the 'top' of the collection. This is the technique used for this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/S5vAG/2/light/

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible though to not just keep it at the top but also force each one over to the far left (or above them all) e.g. if you clicked on number 6 it would move all the way over to the left past number 1.